# UINavigationBar background color setted from storyboard differ from the color setted by code

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, swift

My app will be available only for `iOS 8` and I'm working with `XCode 6.1.1`.

If I set the color through the storyboard (setting the`Bar Tint` attribute on `Navigation Bar` section)

The desired color is:

> 56 186 145

I used [Core coding utilities](http://www.corecoding.com/utilities/rgb-or-hex-to-float.php) to get the floating values of my color.

By code:

```
let backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.22, green: 0.729, blue: 0.569, alpha: 1.0)
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = backgroundColor
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.translucent = false
```

Color setted through storyboard is the same as the Original RGB.

- By code:
  [image]
- By storyboard:
  [image]

---

EDIT

I tried using `let backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.255, green: 0.769, blue: 0.635, alpha: 1.0)` and rgb from storyboard: `65 196 162` based on @siejkowski comment, but I get these colors:

- By code:
  [image]
- By storyboard:
  [image]

Why?

Comment: Where are you setting this? viewDidLoad()?

Comment: Yes, I run that in the viewDidLoad

Comment: Could you provide the image showing the difference in colors?

Comment: I just updated the question with the images @siejkowski

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is two reason for the color differences here you observed.

1. The value set in Storyboard is **RGB (sRGB IEC61966-2.1)** type and when you code `UIColor` by RGB value it will return **RGB (Generic RGB)** values.

So when you change color from Storyboard the values are different for RBG types. To get exact RGB value change type of **RGB Sliders** in Storyboard.

Click on Settings icon which is exactly right to the **RGB Sliders** Option. It will show a pop-up menu - select **Generic RGB** option.

[image]

Now you can observe an image that values for RGB

```
56 186 145
```

is now change to

```
49 175 126
```

So these are desire values to code.

2. **Roundup issue:**

In code, you are passing giving round up values for parameter like in below line

```
UIColor(red: 0.22, green: 0.729, blue: 0.569, alpha: 1.0)
```

So it will make a small change per pixel of the color code. I suggest you divide this values by `255` and leave round up calculation for the compiler. Which will gives you desire color accuracy.

So now for new values update code will be:

```
let backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 49.0/255.0, green: 175.0/255.0, blue: 126.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = backgroundColor
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

Comment: I received an RGB color code from my designer (13/89/165) it is in Generic RBG format, so when I set it from storyboard after changing to Generic RGB it works. But when I try to programatically set the color it turns out to be in a diff color. Any solution ?

Comment: have you check this color in device? Are you using simulator?

Comment: Yes I am using simulator.

Comment: Please check once in device, it may be different in device. Some times machine's color calibration is different

Answer (score 2):

You see the difference in colors because they are set using the same RGB values, but in different color-spaces.

UIColor, when set from code, interprets the values as from sRGB space, as provided here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGColorSpace/index.html

However, it seems that the Storyboard color picker is using native values RGB by default. You need to convert between the two. You can do it in Storyboard color picker by clicking the settings icon next to *RGB Sliders* list picker in *Colors* tab. Native RGB values are set under *Color LCD* setting and sRGB values are under *sRGB*, of course.

[image]

When you do it, is seems that `56 186 145` in native RGB space is `73 186 141` in sRGB space. So your code needs to be:

```
let backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.286, green:0.729, blue:0.553, alpha:1.0)
```

Comment: I tried man but still differs from the storyboard one, I updated the answer, check the bottom.

Comment: Do you know an online converter for those spaces?

Comment: I was wrong. The RGB values are under *Color LCD* setting, so I've converted them wrong. I've updated the answer. This is just a pain in the butt, I must admit. I do not know any online converters, but every graphics program (Photoshop, GIMP, you name it) would be able to do such a conversion.

Answer (score 1):

When I try to change the color space to *GenericRGB* from the storyboard/Interface builder (on XCode 6.3.2), XCode does not save the change. So if I reopen the color from Interface builder the color space is always *sRGBIEC61966-2.1.*

So I came up a different solution that may be useful for someone else:
with the Mac OS default app "*ColorSync Utility"* I used the Calculator and translate the value of my color from *GenericRGB* to a *sRGBIEC61966-2.1*. Then I set the translated value into the Interface builder and I obtained the same result as was obtaining it programmatically!

[image: Color Sync screenshot]