# View Controller Background Color Convert to Hex Color with code in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, uicolor

I add view controller background color in Attributes Inspector. The color is "00466E". 
[image]

But, I add the color with code in one of my view controllers. I need to convert color code to Hexcolor.

```
var window_background: String! = "00466E"
window_background = match.value(forKey: "window_background") as! String
collectionview.backgroundColor = UIColor().HexToColor(hexString: window_background)<br>
```

After I add this code and run the project, the background color result is not the one I want.
It changes a little bit.

[image]

Anyone can explain me how this color occurs when I add color convert code? Please help me.

Comment: `HexToColor(hexString:)` What's that method?

Comment: @May Phyu you can get RGB Color code of your color from storyboard and apply same rgb code in class.

Comment: @Larme, I would like to convert the color code into string because when I get the color code(string) from server is "100" (for e.g..), then the app theme color including background color will change into other color. That it is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use hex colour values in Swift, iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24263007/how-to-use-hex-colour-values-in-swift-ios)

Comment: Check out this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27628473/uinavigationbar-background-color-setted-from-storyboard-differ-from-the-color-se/27632680#27632680) too, may be it can help.

Answer (score 3):

You can use it:

```
extension UIColor {

    convenience init(hex: Int) {
        let components = (
            R: CGFloat((hex >> 16) & 0xff) / 255,
            G: CGFloat((hex >> 08) & 0xff) / 255,
            B: CGFloat((hex >> 00) & 0xff) / 255
        )

        self.init(red: components.R, green: components.G, blue: components.B, alpha: 1)
    }

}
```

then while calling :

```
view.backgroundColor =  UIColor(hex:0x00466E)
```